# xampp on Mac H/S 10.13.5 cannot see web files anymore

Tags: macos, xampp

I've been working in XAMPP on Mac.  I created a folder for my websites under htdocs (same folder as dashboard).  Recently upgraded to High Sierra 10.13.4 and SublimeText started acting weird - it would hang up when saving a new file and I would have to force-quit to get it to stop.  I decided it would take less time to copy-paste files into that folder.  During one copy-paste operation, finder hung and I had to force-quit finder.  Now, the files in the website folders are "missing" - actually just invisible.  I can't see them, but they are still there when I open the browser.  I just can't see them or modify them anymore.

I've search everywhere for this issue and have come up short.  Any suggestions on where to search next?

Comment: I've done full uninstall and reinstall of xampp and sublime with no change in results.  I can't even "start over" from my backups.